# Access the sibling nodes from current node in XPath

Tags: xpath

```
<div class="form-group value">
    <label>Text
        <a href="#" class="">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
        </a>
    </label>
    <div>
        <input/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can we access the `span` element with the class `glyphicon glyphicon-pencil` from `input` element.

Comment: Why don't you simply access the `span` through its `class` attribute? Without any detailed question or code it is hard to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the simplest way maybe using `preceding` axis which will find previous elements relative to current context element regardless of the parent/level (I assume that the current context element here is the `<input/>` element) :

```
preceding::span[@class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil']
```

contrasts with `preceding-sibling` axis which only match previous element within the same parent (in other words, previous element at the same level).

Comment: As the attribute will be atomic, can I suggest using `eq` instead of `=`

Comment: @adamretter I can see your point, but `eq` is not available in XPath 1.0 and we don't know what version OP has